# How can I automatically attach posts to a map?

Tags: posts, google-maps, geo-data

I'd like to display a Google map of places relating to posts (eg, places I've visited).

Is there a plugin or method available that will allow me to have a Google map on a page and when creating a post, I can put in an address or lat/long for the post, so that it automatically gets added to the map?

I'm thinking of something a bit like Drupal's Location module, which adds nodes with lat/longs to a main map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/romeluv-google-maps-for-wordpress/), although it may only be compatible to 3.2.1. And [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codepeople-post-map/) may help you out, although it seems a little complicated to implement a map for all the posts.

You could also use a custom field for lat/long on each post, and then create markers using wpdb calls, grabbing the post_meta data, and using the Google Maps API to place the markers, but it sounds as though you'd prefer an out-of-the-box solution. If you do want to attempt this, you might use the above plugin's code as a development roadmap.

Comment: Interesting - both seem to be ideal, at first glance. Thanks!